React Native no detecta Android SDK
No entiendo por qué en el siguiente mensaje no me detecta el sdk
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\proyect2> npx react-native doctor
Common
✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
✓ yarn - Required to install NPM dependencies
● Metro - Metro Bundler is not running
Android
✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
✓ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

Versions found: 34.0.0, 35.0.0
Version supported: .b34.0.0

Errors:   1
Warnings: 1

El problema se indica en el mensaje:

Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

SDK de Android: necesario para crear e instalar su aplicación en Android.
Debes instalar y definir el SDK para tu aplicación, para esto puedes abrir el archivo local.properties y definir la ruta donde se localiza tu Android SDK, ejemplo:
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\jorgesys\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk

Esto debe solucionar el problema.
